# Making UIBezierPath more like NSBezierPath with elementCount and elementAtIndex

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uibezierpath

When moving some Cocoa code to Cocoa Touch I was disappointed to find that UIBezierPath is missing the "Accessing Elements of a Path" methods:

```
– elementCount
– elementAtIndex:
– elementAtIndex:associatedPoints:
– removeAllPoints
– setAssociatedPoints:atIndex:
```

The only way to get at these elements in Cocoa Touch seems to be through `CGPathApply`. Before I try to recreate this as a subclass or category of UIBezierPath, I was wondering if this had already been done. Does anyone have an idea if something like this is already available?

Comment: I am not sure but this might be bit helpful https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/blob/master/UIKit/UIBezierPath.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a port on https://github.com/seivan/UIBezierPathPort but it's with Swift.
Has a test suite and documentation.
Works as of Beta 5.

Technically you should be able to use Swift on a Obj-C project.

Let me know how you like it.

Answer (score 1):

I've bumped into the same problem a couple of months ago and couldn't find anything readily available back then. (Truth be told, since going the `CGPathApply` route wasn't that bad for my needs, I didn't look very hard to be honest).

The applier function is called for every `CGPathElement` in the `CGPath`, such an element consists of a `CGPathElementType` and a C-array of `CGPoints`.

Since a `CGPathElementType` is an enum with only five different values

```
enum CGPathElementType {
   kCGPathElementMoveToPoint,
   kCGPathElementAddLineToPoint,
   kCGPathElementAddQuadCurveToPoint,
   kCGPathElementAddCurveToPoint,
   kCGPathElementCloseSubpath
};
```

You don't need to write that much code to do (control)point manipulation / inspection of a path. Having the same interface available would've been nice though.